# Construir un UserControl en funcion de un archivo (WPF)

Tags: c#, xaml

Supongamos que tengo este codigo en XAML

```
     <StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="4" IsChecked="True" Content="Acometida 5P (4mm)"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" Text="1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="1" Text="32" Background="#eee"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Margin="1" Text="32" Background="#eee"/>
    </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Y con este codigo genero el siguiente control;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que, sin tocar el XAML pudiese generar nuevas lineas de referencias en las cuales ir guardando nuevos componentes para que cada vez que cargase esa vista se muestren todas las referencias que he ido metiendo en el archivo (si es que es un archivo) Soy nuevo en WPF y igual estoy pidiendo algo muy obvio o fácil de hacer pero ahora mismo no sabría muy bien como...
Me daría lo mismo que tipo de archivo usar para ello, lo único que necesito es tener cuantas referencias me hagan falta.

¿Hay alguna manera "profesional" de hacerlo o al menos con buenas practicas? No me gustaria hacerlo en plan casero, la idea es hacerlo bien y aprender, al fin y al cabo es un programita que estoy haciendo para practicar.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Si te entiendo bien, lo que necesitas es un listado de ítems que manejen unos controles como checkbox y textbox. Si esto es así, hay controles para hacer esto como el GridView o el Listview. Acá te dejo un par de links: 
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/  
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/simple-listview/

Comment: No... no es eso lo que necesito, necesito cargar desde un archivo los nuevos items, no tener items fijos

Comment: OK, igual el Listview o el GridView se usan justamente para eso, para cargar listados dinámicos desde la fuente de datos que tu dispongas.

Comment: Gracias, pensaba que habías entendido otra cosa, ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo en el que se haga lo que pido? Gracias

Comment: Para poderte ayudar necesitaríamos que edites la pregunta y pongas la estructura del archivo que estas usando y el código que has intentado hacer para cargar ese archivo.

Comment: El problema es que no sé cómo crear ese archivo... El código que pongo es lo que tengo actualmente pero intento hacer eso mismo pero leyéndolo en un archivo que ahora no existe.

Comment: No se muy bien donde encontrar informacion al respecto, la documentacion del MSDN es de lo peor que conozco y por mucho que busco no logro encontrar nada al respecto, Tengo dudas de concepto en este tema. Para hacer lo que necesito deberia hacerlo desde el XAML ya que se trata de la vista la que quiero cambiar? Se que podria hacerlo desde el Code Behind pero tengo entendido que seria ir para atras en cuanto a "estructuracion"...
Agradecería un enlace con algun ejemplo basico, al menos para entender el funcionamiento de lo que busco

Gracias

Comment: OK, acá te dejo un ejemplo que te puede dar una idea de como hacerlo, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813461/reading-a-csv-file-into-wpf-application-c